# I need an example of using =* in an AngularJS directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've tried to build an example of a directive using =* instead of = (which is supposed to do a shallow watch ala $watchCollection) but everything I create still seems to react to changes, even very deep changes, within a single object in an array of objects whether I use =* or just =.

I created one example where I assigned a value multiple levels deep when I clicked a button and even watching with =* the directive still seemed to notice the change. I did not expect that. I had expected that the directive would only notice changes to the members of the array (for example, removing an item or adding a new one).

Can you show me a working example where a directive acts differently if you use =*?

Comment: P.S. Here's the CodePen I was playing with when trying to figure this out: http://codepen.io/JohnMunsch/pen/oXgBbd.html

Comment: interesting I din't heard about `=*` in directive isolated scope & didn't found anylink..could you able share the link wherever you found this

Comment: Sure. You can look on the documentation for $compile (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) and the scope part of the page talks about both =* and =*? I've also found code in AngularJS itself which tries to set this up. I just haven't been able to make an example which demonstrates it.